# Importing an IONIC project to a new computer

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, npm, ionic-framework

I'll explain the situation that I'm in, I'm not really a software developer (I'm firmware developer), but I know some basic
Recently the member of my team that programmed the front end of an application left the company, and he left us whit the files that he programmed in IONIC, the thing is that I can't really run the project

**What i have done**

- Downloaded the files from a github repository
- Install IONIC
- Made a example project for IONIC
- open the github project, run -ionic serve, it returned:

> > react-scripts start
>
> [INFO] Looks like react-scripts isn't installed in this project.
>
> This package is required for this command to work properly. The package provides a   CLI utility, but the
> react-scripts binary was not found in your PATH.
>
> ? Install react-scripts? Yes
>
> > npm i -D -E react-scripts
>
> > react-scripts start
>
> [ERROR] react-scripts command not found.

- Tried npm update, it returned:

> npm install
>
> npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
>
> npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
>
> npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
>
> npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
>
> npm WARN deprecated acorn-dynamic-import@2.0.2: This is probably built in to whatever tool you're using. If you still need it... idk
>
> npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
>
> npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
>
> npm WARN deprecated formidable@1.2.6: Please upgrade to latest, formidable@v2 or formidable@v3! Check these notes: xxxxx
>
> npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
>
> npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
>
> npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
>
> npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
>
> npm WARN deprecated dommatrix@1.0.3: dommatrix is no longer maintained. Please use @thednp/dommatrix.
>
> npm WARN deprecated workbox-cacheable-response@6.6.0: workbox-background-sync@6.6.0
>
> npm WARN deprecated workbox-cacheable-response@6.6.0: workbox-background-sync@6.6.0
>
> npm WARN deprecated vm2@3.9.19: The library contains critical security issues and should not be used for production! The maintenance of the project has been discontinued. Consider migrating your code to isolated-vm.
>
> npm WARN deprecated superagent@5.3.1: Please upgrade to v7.0.2+ of superagent.  We have fixed numerous issues with streams, form-data, attach(), filesystem errors not bubbling up (ENOENT on attach()), and all tests are now passing.  See the releases tab for more information at https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/releases.
>
> npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
>
> npm ERR! code 1
>
> npm ERR! path /home/-----/Proyectos/LCS_APP/frontend/node_modules/node-pty
>
> npm ERR! command failed
>
> npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/install.js
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/-----/.npm/_logs/2023-07-24T16_45_55_268Z-debug-0.log

As a reference, here is the package.json file:

```
{
"homepage": "/",
"name": "sunandplay",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@capacitor/android": "4.6.1",
  "@capacitor/app": "^4.1.1",
  "@capacitor/clipboard": "^4.1.0",
  "@capacitor/core": "4.6.1",
  "@capacitor/geolocation": "^4.1.0",
  "@capacitor/google-maps": "^4.3.2",
  "@capacitor/haptics": "4.1.0",
  "@capacitor/keyboard": "4.1.0",
  "@capacitor/status-bar": "4.1.1",
  "@ionic/react": "^6.0.0",
  "@ionic/react-router": "^6.0.0",
  "@ionic/storage": "^3.0.6",
  "@react-pdf-viewer/core": "^3.11.0",
  "@react-pdf-viewer/default-layout": "^3.11.0",
  "@react-pdf-viewer/toolbar": "^3.11.0",
  "@react-pdf-viewer/zoom": "^3.11.0",
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
  "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.3",
  "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
  "@types/node": "^12.19.15",
  "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
  "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
  "@types/react-router": "^5.1.11",
  "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
  "axios": "^1.2.2",
  "decko": "^1.2.0",
  "history": "^4.9.0",
  "ionicons": "^6.0.3",
  "node-pty": "^0.10.1",
  "pdfjs-dist": "^3.6.172",
  "pm2": "^5.2.2",
  "preact": "^10.12.1",
  "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-code-input": "^3.10.1",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  "react-pdf-viewer": "^0.1.0",
  "react-router": "^5.2.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
  "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
  "react-window": "^1.8.8",
  "socket.io-client": "^4.5.4",
  "typescript": "^4.1.3",
  "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
  "workbox-background-sync": "^5.1.4",
  "workbox-broadcast-update": "^5.1.4",
  "workbox-cacheable-response": "^5.1.4",
  "workbox-core": "^5.1.4",
  "workbox-expiration": "^5.1.4",
  "workbox-google-analytics": "^5.1.4",
  "workbox-navigation-preload": "^5.1.4",
  "workbox-precaching": "^5.1.4",
  "workbox-range-requests": "^5.1.4",
  "workbox-routing": "^5.1.4",
  "workbox-strategies": "^5.1.4",
  "workbox-streams": "^5.1.4",
  "xterm-addon-attach": "^0.8.0",
  "xterm-addon-fit": "^0.7.0",
  "xterm-addon-search": "^0.11.0"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "PORT=4000 react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns 'node_modules/(?!(@ionic/react|@ionic/react-router|@ionic/core|@stencil/core|ionicons)/)'",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest"
  ]
},
"browserslist": {
  "production": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "development": [
    "last 1 chrome version",
    "last 1 firefox version",
    "last 1 safari version"
  ]
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@capacitor/cli": "4.6.1",
  "@ionic/cli": "6.20.6",
  "@types/react-pdf": "^6.2.0",
  "cordova-res": "0.15.4",
  "worker-loader": "^3.0.8"
},
"description": "Sun and play project"
}
```

**What help I need**

The first and most obvious, if someone could give directions onto how to fix all these problems, if not, if someone could give directions onto how to learn to fix all these problems, it will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Update NPM and Node.js?

Comment: Can you have access to the previous developper's computer? These tools are great, but having used some of them, they are quite sensitive to versions. Many times the code will not be compatible to older or newer versions, the best would be to install the exact version of the tools than what the original developper used. It's really better if there was an install guide (I always do one in .txt format, because even myself don't remember all sometimes), maybe you can ask them if there is one? Note that those builds typically produce lots of warning you can ignore, but only experience will tell you

Answer (score 1):

You missed a lot of important info about your project config but a general idea would be:
You need to run `npm i` to install node modules. Then `ionic build` to build project. If app uses native ios and android you must install the platforms as well (look at ionic docs, it shows how) and then you will be able to do `ionic serve`.

Also you need to make sure you had the proper node/npm and ionic installed, if not you will get a lot of errors.